# Why is Graphite UI not showing Data even after all the data is reaching the Graphite DB?

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I have a graphite server which has the following retention.

```
[default]
pattern = .*
retentions = 10s:7d,5m:30d,10m:2y
```

I send data every 10seconds from system A to the Graphite server I can confirm that required data is reaching from system A. I have checked the wsp file in the location /storage/whisper/ and the data is present(used whisper-fetch.py). However, I am still not able to see any graphs on Graphite UI.

Also, all the directories regarding system A are visible in Graphite UI, but when I click on the metric it shows no data.

Please help me on possible reasons for this issue as this is happening only for system A, there are other systems for which I can see the Data in Graphite.

Comment: There are a few possibilities: 1) the data is there but invisible: When you click on the metric in the Graphite UI directory display, do you get an empty graph, or a message saying No Data? If you change the date range does the display change at all? If the graph is just empty with no message, try changing [lineMode](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#linemode) to `connected`. 2) Something about the metric means Graphite can't display it. Are there strange characters in the metric name, e.g. colons. Use browser dev tools to check if data is actually being retrieved

Comment: Hey, thank you, I have figured out the issue, the issue in my case was the way the the name of the metric had ",". So when I removed the ",". all the data was visible.